# cannot ping to ip base on host name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

i have two PC

```
1. 192.168.56.102 => winXP
2. 192.168.56.103 => ubuntu 10.04 (bind9 and apache2 installed)
```

i have registered simas.tes to 192.168.56.103

what i did :

```
# vi /etc/bind/named.conf.local

zone "simas.tes" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/simas.tes.db";
};

zone "56.168.192.in-addr-arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.56.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

then :

```
# vi /etc/bind/zones/simas.tes.db

simas.tes.  IN  SOA ns1.simas.tes.  admin.simas.tes. (
    2006081401
    28800
    3600
    604800
    38400
)

simas.tes.  IN  NS      NS1.simas.tes. 
simas.tes.  IN  MX  10  mta.simas.tes.

www IN  A   192.168.56.103
mta IN  A   192.168.56.103
ns1 IN  A   192.168.56.103
```

then :

```
# vi /etc/bind/zones/rev.56.168.192.in-addr.arpa

@ IN SOA ns1.simas.tes. admin.simas.tes. (
    2006081401;
    28800;
    604600;
    604800;
    86400
)

    IN  NS  ns1.simas.tes.
103 IN  PTR simas.tes.
```

my dig state :

```
root@my-ubuntu:/var/www# dig simas.tes

; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> simas.tes
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9559
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;simas.tes.         IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
simas.tes.      38400   IN  SOA ns1.simas.tes. admin.simas.tes. 2006081401 28800 3600 604800 38400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.56.103#53(192.168.56.103)
;; WHEN: Thu May  3 17:25:05 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 73
```

my nslookup state :

```
root@my-ubuntu:/var/www# nslookup simas.tes
Server:     192.168.56.103
Address:    192.168.56.103#53

*** Can't find simas.tes: No answer
```

now i can access simas.tes site from 192.168.56.102 (my winXP), but i cannot ping to simas.tes (instead of 192.168.56.103)..
what i miss? .. i just want to know how to ping simas.tes successfully.

Comment: zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in your reverse DNS might better be zone "56.168.192.in-addr.arpa"...

Comment: i got problem with this code, i have put that reserve DNS before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're missing an "IN A" entry for "simas.tes." in the /etc/bind/zones/simas.tes.db file. One possibility to set that would be:

```
simas.tes.  IN A       192.168.56.103
simas.tes.  IN NS      NS1.simas.tes.
```

In this example, I added the "A" record I mentioned above your existing NS record.